# Is there a str.join() for lists?

Tags: python, list

I understand `str.join()`:

```
>>> '|'.join(['1','2','3'])
'1|2|3'
```

Is there something which outputs a list? Is there a function that will output:

```
['1', '|', '2','|', '3']
```

That is, a `str.join()` for lists? (or any other iterable?)

Answer (score 5):

```
list('|'.join(['1','2','3']))
```

should do the trick where you are working with a list of chars.

A more generic solution, that works for all objects is:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain

def intersperse(myiter, value):
    return list(
        chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(myiter, [], fillvalue=value))
    )[:-1]
```

I'm not aware of a built-in/std-library version of this function.

In action:

```
print intersperse([1,2,3], '|')
```

outputs:

```
[1, '|', 2, '|', 3]
```

Comment: The first only works if each string in the list is a single character. `list('|'.join(['ab', 'c'])) -> 'a|b|c'` whereas `'ab|c'` makes more sense and is more consistent with `str.join`.

Comment: @delnan, your first example actually produces `['a', 'b', '|', 'c']`, probably not what the OP wants either though

Comment: Yes, brainfart on my part. Unfortunately I can't edit any more.

Comment: @delnan, no worries... I missed some obvious points in my original version, so you were still helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: I would argue that instead of ``zip_longest()``, the clearer option is using [``itertools.repeat()``](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) - ``list(chain.from_iterable(zip(myiter, repeat(value))))[:-1]``

Comment: +1 to @Lattyware's version being clearer, though in py2 you'd probably want `izip` instead of `zip`.

Comment: @Dougal As it's being converted directly to a list anyway, I doubt it'll matter much either way.

Comment: @Lattyware Sure, but if `myiter` is very large then the `izip` version would presumably use about half as much memory. Might be a little slower for reasonably-sized iterables though; probably not a huge difference either way.

Comment: @Lattywar good point, I only used izip_longest because it was the first to come to my mind.  If I were using something like Haskell (that has no izip_longest), I would've used repeat.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
>>> list('|'.join(['1','2','3']))
['1', '|', '2', '|', '3']
```

Comment: I assume he means something generic that works with any type of objects. obj0.join([obj1, obj2]) => [obj1, obj0, obj2]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 'str', 'foo']
print [x for y in a for x in y, '|'][:-1]
# [1, '|', 2, '|', 'str', '|', 'foo']
```

For the general case, consider the `roundrobin` [itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Answer (score 0):

This simple generator avoids building a list (faster, saves memory):

```
def intersperse(iterable, element):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    yield next(iterable)
    while True:
        next_from_iterable = next(iterable)
        yield element
        yield next_from_iterable
```

Example:

```
>>> list(intersperse(['1', '2', '3'], '|'))
['1', '|', '2', '|', '3']
```